# Get "Forbidden. Need user" when request messagesWithDialogID

Tags: quickblox

I get the same response every time I request history messages from Quickblock.

I already search for some topics in here, and they say I'm not logged in or I don't have permission to do that. I'm pretty sure I'm logged in and I have a permission. Everything works fine I can send, receive message but I can't get the history.

## Here is the code

```
[QBRequest messagesWithDialogID:myId extendedRequest:nil forPage:resPage successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, NSArray *messages, QBResponsePage *responcePage) {



    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", response.error);
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be logged in as a user in order to request your messages

Read this guide about session creation

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios#Login_to_Chat

You can do **[QBRequest createSession...]** or **[QBRequest logIn...]**

Comment: Thanks for the replay, but I did it already . I solved this problem by login twice once from   
 [[QBChat instance] loginWithUser:currentUser];
and 1 more with  
[QBRequest logInWithUserLogin:[[UserModel currentUser] facebookId] password:[[UserModel currentUser] facebookId] successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBUUser *user)

This is a weird solution but at lest I can get it through